# CMake Error while installing sqliteman on Linux

Tags: linux, sqlite

This is the first time for me to install `sqliteman` on Linux , I faced the following error and I don't know how to solve it , any ideas ?

```
root@kali:~# cmake --version
cmake version 2.8.9
root@kali:~# qmake --version
QMake version 2.01a
Using Qt version 4.8.2 in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
root@kali:~# cd ~/mydownloads/sqliteman-1.2.2
root@kali:~/mydownloads/sqliteman-1.2.2# cmake .
-- Sqliteman 1.2.2 will be installed into /usr/local
--  *** Release build (use -DWANT_DEBUG=1 for debug one) ***
-- Qt4version:4.8.2
-- Qt4includes:/usr/include/qt4/QtDesigner/usr/include/qt4/QtDeclarative/usr/include/qt4/QtScriptTools/usr/include/qt4/QtDBus/usr/include/qt4/QtDesigner/usr/include/qt4/QtXml/usr/include/qt4/QtSql/usr/include/qt4/QtOpenGL/usr/include/qt4/QtNetwork/usr/include/qt4/QtXmlPatterns/usr/include/qt4/QtWebKit/usr/include/qt4/QtHelp/usr/include/qt4/QtUiTools/usr/include/qt4/QtTest/usr/include/qt4/QtScript/usr/include/qt4/QtSvg/usr/include/qt4/Qt3Support/usr/include/qt4/QtGui/usr/include/qt4/QtCore/usr/share/qt4/mkspecs/default/usr/include/qt4/usr/include/qt4/QtCore
-- Qt4libs:/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
CMake Error at cmake/modules/FindQScintilla.cmake:53 (MESSAGE):
  Could not find QScintilla library
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:132 (FIND_PACKAGE)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
```

Comment: `Could not find QScintilla library` --- do you have this lib?

Comment: i have only `FindQScintilla.cmake` in `/root/mydownloads/sqliteman-1.2.2/cmake/modules`

Comment: So you should consider installing `QScintilla library` first....

Comment: what is the command to install it please ?

Comment: `google` or `bing` is your best friend for answering this question :)

Comment: thanks for your help :D sqliteman installed :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I found for Ubuntu Trusty 14.04 is to install all qscintilla2 packages as in here:
http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/trusty/main/base/qscintilla2

then it works.

Answer (score 0):

In this case your friend is `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install libqscintilla2-12v5
```